# golang: emailing an image stored as a Google Appengine blobstore blob

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm trying to read a JPEG file stored in the GAE blobstore back into a byte array using the following code:

```
info,_  := blobstore.Stat(context,appengine.BlobKey(request.FormValue("blobkey")))
image   := make([]byte,info.Size)
reader  := blobstore.NewReader(context,appengine.BlobKey(request.FormValue("blobkey")))
n,nerr  := reader.Read(image)
```

The image is stored correctly i.e. it can be served using blobstore.Send(...).

And the above code sort of works (in that it does read back the blob data) but it converts any 0x0a byte into a 0x0d 0x0a pair (i.e. LF into CR LF).

Is there a way in Go to work around this behaviour (without writing a filter to convert 0x0d0a back to 0x0a) ?

EDIT:

It turns out the problem is not with Blobstore.Reader at all, but with the attachment encoding in mail.py on the dev appserver.

Comment: I've had this happen with Python 2.7 as well but I dont have a solution.

Comment: Thanks - was going to check it in Python so that saves me a bunch of work :-). Have posted it as a defect on the appengine issue tracker: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7587

Comment: Probsably you must set a proper content-type?

Comment: Printing out the info from the above snippet shows the correct mime-type, file size and file name, so I don't think it's that, unless there is some way to set the mime-type for the Reader ? Caveat: it might be just an SDK issue - am still tweaking the code to get the blobstore stuff to run correctly on the real GAE.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this error on the development server or in production: http://7587.proppy-bugs.appspot.com/serve2/?blobKey=AMIfv96eSvXFrC2eKkX620bJ26HWoqkRUtntcGG4G-Jkdau-tmD7nd3q0HSaZOHjE43-HS-4OdIJ9QeJE33sPn3OdGb_noFERW00gODs5LwTmuQGnvXhzqSnKeAmXf2_RlDpxTKbsBGMWIiyMnW86dluRy1FnbONd8Hq68mASssmAgq3BmKrgmI
Are you settings the content-type header correctly w/ `      w.Header().Set("Content-Type", info.ContentType)` when serving the blob back to the user?

Comment: @proppy Uh ... the content-type header is irrelevant here. blobstore.Send (which is what I assume you are using to serve the image ?) serves up the image correctly. The byte array (needed for some internal image processing) contains invalid data when it is filled by the Reader returned  by blobstore.NewReader.

Comment: Sorry if that wasn't clear confusion: `/serve2` is serving the byte array coming from `blobstore.Reader`, `/serve` is serving the blob using `blobstore.Send`.

Comment: Ah, ok - thanks :-). I'll try that this evening and see if I get the same results - maybe it's a Mac OSX issue.

Comment: <light dawns suddenly> the problem is most likely with whatever is creating the e-mail attachment from the byte array. Aaargh ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mail attachment handling on the dev appserver does not correctly encode image data. If the attachment data is known to be binary, a partial workaround is to add the line:

```
encoders.encode_base64(mime_attachment)
```

after the line

```
mime_attachment.set_payload(attachment.data())
```

in the file

> google/appengine/api/mail.py

Using a MIMEImage attachment for an image content type would be a better solution but causes a 'LazyImporter object is not callable' error.

Comment: Probably you are not interested in this yet, but in reference to your last comment, did you tried to import MIMEImage as

    `from email.mime.image import MIMEImage`

or maybe as

    `from email import MIMEImage`
??

If you tried to import it as the second way, that's the reason why you got that `LazyImporter object is not callable` exception.

Comment: @José Luis Patiño: Yup, you are exactly right - thanks !

I've added it as a comment to the issue raised at http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7608